Unable to access SSH, buplickey, password error

This is the information about the error when I try to access the SSH server.
I hope somebody can help me with it.

Usually this suggests the password you're submitting is incorrect. Or that the user you're connecting as is invalid.  Have you confirmed these things?  As it stands, there's no evidence you have any real issue other than a bad password

My VPS shows a Root password, and that's the one I am trying to use, I asked my VPS provider to reset it but they told me that cannot be reset which is weird.
I can access the VPS normally using remote desktop app on my computer, but I cannot access the VPS through SSH on Ubuntu.

I also tried using the password to access the VPS on remote desktop app which is different than the root password on my admin dashboard, but I got the same result.
